# To use toFixed() in Select - SAP UI5

Tags: sapui5

I have the following select statement: My issue is OrderQty is always coming in 3 decimals like 5.000. I want to get rid of that decimals. Usually I would write a toFixed() method. But I am not understanding how to write it here. Or even call a formatter. Please help me with the syntax. My point of confusion is because I am concatenating 3 different bindings together.

***XML.View***

```
<Select width="100%" items="{order>/material/materialSet/results}" 
                        forceSelection="false" change="materialSelected">
                        <core:Item text="Lot No: {order>ONumber} - Date: {order>Date} - Quantity:{order>OrderQty}" key="{order>ONumber}"/>
                    </Select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below syntax :

```xml
<Select
  width="100%"
  items="{order>/material/materialSet/results}"
  forceSelection="false"
  change=".materialSelected"
>
  <core:Item
    key="{order>ONumber}"
    text="{
      parts: [
        {path: 'order>ONumber'},
        {path: 'order>Date'},
        {path:'order>OrderQty'}
      ],
      formatter: '.formatter.myFormatter'
    }
  />
</Select>
```

Your formatter function must have three parameters:

```js
myFormatter: function(oNumber, Date, OrderQt) {
  // ...
}
```